# Decimal Subtraction problems in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

when i subtract 6.4-1.6 i am getting the answer as 4.800000000000001 in JS, but i need as 4.8 without using toFixed(), toPrecision() and Math.round(). any idea???

Thanks,

crystal

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Convert to integers before doing the subtraction to avoid problems with floating point arithmetic:

```
(6.4 * 10 - 1.6 * 10) / 10
```

See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: This is not true. When you calculate different numbers, you will get same error. E.g. (6.41 * 10 - 1.61 * 10) / 10 = 4.799999999999999
The corrent solution is: (6.4  - 1.6 ).toFixed(2) (2 is the decimals count)

Comment: @MuminKa _convert to integer_ in your case means `(6.41 * 100 - 1.61 * 100) / 100 = 4.8`. The question asked for solutions without using toFixed().

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the actual demand :() @Mark

Answer (score 6):

This is a [well-known limitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) of IEEE 754 floating point numbers.  See [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem) for solutions.